# javac compile error on java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, javac

I' try to write some code to learn how to use protocol buffer in java and here is the folder structure:

```
- JAVA
    - com
        - game
            - enumeration
                - GameEnumProtos.java
            - info
                - GameInfoProtos.java

    - JAVA_TEST.java
    - protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
```

JAVA_TEST.java:

```
import com.game.info.GameInfoProtos;

public class JAVA_TEST {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

and how I compile (no error or warning):

```
javac JAVA_TEST.java ./com/game/info/GameInfoProtos.java ./com/game/enumeration/GameEnumProtos.java -classpath protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
```

and when I try to run the code I got the error:

```
java JAVA_TEST
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JAVA_TEST (wrong name: com/JAVA_TEST)
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

@Albert

I tried what you suggested (macos) running

```
java -cp protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:. com.game.info.GameInfoProtos .JAVA_TEST
```

in the "java" folder, but got the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class .JAVA_TEST
```

Comment: in wich directory you are running the java comment?

Comment: go to your `JAVA` directory, and run as `java -cp protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:. com.game.info.GameInfoProtos.JAVA_TEST`. **Note**: Replace `:` in  `-cp` for `;` if you are under Windows OS.

Comment: Did you forget to include the `package` at the beginning of your class (e.g. `JAVA_TEST` must include `package com;`) ? I just created the same directory, compiled it like Albert, all is alright.

Comment: My JAVA_TEST.java is inside the folder "JAVA" not the folder "com" -- do I still have to add the "package com;" into JAVA_TEST.java ?  Or do I need to move JAVA_TEST.java into the "com" folder ???

Comment: JAVA_TEST.java should be in the folder `com/game/info/GameInfoProtos` to match its package of `com.game.info.GameInfoProtos`. You should compile from the directory that contains `com.`

Comment: Read carefully.  You have an extra space in your class name:
java -cp protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:. com.game.info.GameInfoProtos .JAVA_TEST

Comment: This not correct: `My JAVA_TEST.java is inside the folder "JAVA" not the folder "com"`. As @EJP said, your `JAVA_TEST.java` must match your package. So, it must be be in `/<base_dir>/com/game/info/GameInfoProtos/JAVA_TEST.java`. You might need first read some basic literature about packages, like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html) or [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs368/JavaTutorial/NOTES/Packages.html). Also, read Wheezil's comment about extra space.